# Error building node with benchmarking features

Tags: benchmarking

I get the following stacktrace while trying to build my node binary with benchmarking features.

Build command: `cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks`

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `successful_origin`
   --> /home/dylan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pallet-collective-3.0.0/src/lib.rs:872:1
    |
872 | / impl<
873 | |     O: Into<Result<RawOrigin<AccountId, I>, O>> + From<RawOrigin<AccountId, I>>,
874 | |     AccountId: Default,
875 | |     I,
...   |
888 | |     }
889 | | }
    | |_^ missing `successful_origin` in implementation
    |
    = help: implement the missing item: `fn successful_origin() -> OuterOrigin { todo!() }`
```

Comment: Can you specify which repo/tag this error is occurring?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/240/missing-successful-origin-in-implementation-when-running-runtime-benchmarks

Comment: That command works for me on latest substrate master. ( dd8a868ad819666ff81bd94479657be560daf767 , linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you have forgotten to enable the `runtime-benchmarks` feature flag for dependent crates.

Inside of `pallet-collective` this trait is implemented, but is hidden behind a feature flag:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
fn successful_origin() -> O {
    let zero_account_id =
        AccountId::decode(&mut sp_runtime::traits::TrailingZeroInput::zeroes())
            .expect("infinite length input; no invalid inputs for type; qed");
    O::from(RawOrigin::Member(zero_account_id))
}
```

To get this code active, this crate needs to enable the `runtime-benchmarks` feature flag.

For example, if you are writing your runtime library, you will need to include your pallet like:

```rust
pallet-collective = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git" }
```

For all of these dependencies, you need to make sure to enable the feature flags for the downstream crates. For example:

```rust
[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "frame-collective/std",
]
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "frame-collective/runtime-benchmarks",
]
```

Comment: Adding this did the trick and I am able to compile now. Thank you so much!

Comment: please feel free to mark this as the answer to your question