# Missing `successful_origin` in implementation when running runtime-benchmarks

Tags: polkadot, parachain, substrate-node-template, benchmarking

With a fresh [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template)

I ran `cargo build --features runtime-benchmarks`

I got errors from a deep dependency in `pallet_society`, which doesn't seem relevant to the parachain-template's pallets:

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `successful_origin`
    --> /root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/4aeb95f/frame/society/src/lib.rs:1268:1
     |
1268 | impl<T: Config> EnsureOrigin<T::Origin> for EnsureFounder<T> {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `successful_origin` in implementation
     |
     = help: implement the missing item: `fn successful_origin() -> OuterOrigin { todo!() }`
```

But it looks like `fn successful_origin()...` is already [there](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4aeb95f7f38fcd519e2628f32f79044a8fef99d5/frame/society/src/lib.rs#L1278):

```
/// Simple ensure origin struct to filter for the founder account.
pub struct EnsureFounder<T>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
impl<T: Config> EnsureOrigin<T::Origin> for EnsureFounder<T> {
    type Success = T::AccountId;
    fn try_origin(o: T::Origin) -> Result<Self::Success, T::Origin> {
        o.into().and_then(|o| match (o, Founder::<T>::get()) {
            (frame_system::RawOrigin::Signed(ref who), Some(ref f)) if who == f => Ok(who.clone()),
            (r, _) => Err(T::Origin::from(r)),
        })
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    fn successful_origin() -> T::Origin {
        let founder = Founder::<T>::get().expect("society founder should exist");
        T::Origin::from(frame_system::RawOrigin::Signed(founder))
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Origin issue [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/issues/98)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for reporting the issue. The problem here was a missing feature flag which enabled the `runtime-benchmarks` features in downstream dependencies.

The solution for you should simply be to simply enable the `runtime-benchmarks` feature flag on `polkadot-cli` in `./node/Cargo.toml`:

```
[features]
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "parachain-template-runtime/runtime-benchmarks",
    # Add the line below
    "polkadot-cli/runtime-benchmarks",
]
```

We have made an upstream PR to fix this in the future!

https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/991

Comment: aha i see, thank you : )

Comment: I tried using your solution [here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/26) where I am also using branch 'polkadot_v0.9.17' and I had already enabled the runtime-benchmarks feature flag on polkadot-cli, but when I run `cargo check --features runtime-benchmarks` I still get error `missing 'successful_origin' in implementation` that it says is caused by pallet-xcm

Comment: You need to make sure any crates you added to your project have the feature flag correctly setup. If you can prepare a minimal example of your issue, you should open a new question and we can answer it